# How to use XML and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

Using .net 4.5 VS 2012

I am trying to read the data from a XMl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<userCategories>
  <Cat>General</Cat>
  <Cat>Science</Cat>
  <Cat>HelloWorld</Cat>
</userCategories>
```

This is the code that I wrote:

```
//create XML document from file
XDocument myCatList = XDocument.Load(categoryPath);
//get all categories using LINQ
var myCategories =
    from element in myCatList.Descendants("userCategories")
//select all elements in XML where Element has name Cat - mean all if file like i write before
    select element.Element("Cat").Value;
    //create string for result
string data = String.Empty;
use foreach for getting all categories
foreach (var userCat in myCategories)
{
    //put in one string 
    data += string.Format("{0}\n", userCat);
}
```

So I think that this kind of LINQ request must return me a string data with all values (General \n Science \n HelloWorld \n). but as result i got only General.

What have I missed? Why do I get only the Item General instead of all of the nodes from the XML?

Comment: Btw. using `string +=` like this is REALLY bad!

Comment: @Thomas Weller why? - i just add all value to a formated string and then work with it

Comment: Because the string must be completely reallocated on each loop cycle (very slow and causes serious memory fragmentation). That's why `StringBuilder` exists.

Comment: noted thanks for this! use `s.Append(userCat + '\n');` where s - `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myCatList.Descendants("userCategories")` returns the collection of all elements named `<userCategories>`.
You only have one such element.

`select element.Element("Cat")` returns the first `<Cat>` child in each of those elements.

You want to select all of the `<Cat>` elements:

```
from elem myCatList.Descendants("cat")
select elem.Value
```

Comment: i think Descendants return collection of all child elements, so collection of all child elements of `<userCategories>` - `<Cat>`, and than just try to get all elements in this collection. thanks for good explanation. thanks

Comment: @Kirill: No; that would be `.Elements()`

Comment: you mean like `var d = from element in myCatList.Elements("userCategories")
                    select element.Value;`? Try - it's return all in one string

Comment: @Kirill: `Descendants()` and `Elements()` return the elements you ask them for, not their children.  To get the children of that element, call `.Elements()` _on it_.

Answer (score 4):

Using Aggregate also we can solve the problem

```
XDocument myCatList = XDocument.Load(@"D:\a.xml");    
var myCategories = myCatList.Elements("userCategories").Descendants("Cat").Select(s => s.Value).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (s,i) => s.Append(i + "\n"));
```