# How to use LINQ to XML for receiving data in List format

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

use c#, .net 4.5

Yesterday i'm asking about [how to read xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20775478/2012219). As yesterday was explained i can use `Descendants()` and `Elements()` for getting required elements of my file.

Now, i have xml file with some entities

```
<Library>
  <Book>
    <Author>Harrison FORD</Author>
    <Name>Unknown Name</Name>
    <Year>2000</Year>
   <Genre>Unknown Genre</Genre>
    <BookID>fc29b1cf-be41-4ed8-b101-5355396fef10</BookID>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Author>Unknown Author</Author>
    <Name>Unknown Name</Name>
    <Year>2000</Year>
    <Genre>Unknown Genre</Genre>
    <BookID>29b6d74b-71b3-4df6-af0b-d676ff5d23ad</BookID>
  </Book>
...
</Library>
```

What i want - to get list with Books (like `List<Book>`) where Book - its a separate entity with same properties like in xml file.

According to yesterday discussion try to do next

```
//get collection of all books
var myLib = from el in myDoc.Descendants("Library")
     select el.Element("Book");
     //create empty book
     Book addOneBook = new Book();
     //try to get each value and than save to just created book
     foreach (var books in myLib)
     {
     var myBook = from el in books.Descendants("Book")
          select el.Element("Author").Value.Trim();
      addBook.BookAuthor = myBook.ToString(); 
      ...
     //save
      myListWithBooks.Add(addOneBook);
```

I understand it like

[image]

During debuging found, that `books` in `foreach` is like on pic below - exactly what i want

[image]

But, when i try to get value of any element from  - got not exactly requierd value - like

[image]

Think, i something miss. Where i'm wrong? Maybe i not all correctly understanding or something is misiing? Why in first time - all work like i thing, and in second same code return another result?

Aslo, maybe ther is some another way to get information that i need from this XML, but anyway - whant to know where i'm wrong now, with this code.

---

EDIT

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `ToString` on a *query* - that's not on a single element.

Even if you fixed that, you'd add lots of references to the same object to your list... and this can all be done *much* more clearly with LINQ:

```
List<Book> books = myDoc.Root.Elements("Book")
                        .Select(x => new Book { 
                            Author = (string) x.Element("Author"),
                            Name = (string) x.Element("Name"),
                            Year = (int) x.Element("Year"),
                            Genre = (string) x.Element("Genre"),
                            Id = (string) x.Element("BookID")
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

(Note that I've changed the property name from `BookAuthor` to `Author` - it doesn't make sense to repeat the type name on the properties of that type. What other author would a `Book` have other than the book author?)

Comment: I'm assuming there's no appreciable difference between `(string)x.Element("...")` and `x.Element("...").Value`? My natural inclination is to use `Value`, which is why I ask.

Comment: @ledbutter: The difference is that when you cast to string, if the target of the cast is a null reference, a null string will be the result - whereas `.Value` will lead to a `NullReferenceException`. It really depends on whether you want a missing element to lead to an exception or to continue with a null reference, basically...

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. Never thought of that implication before.

Comment: @Jon Skeet try this code, but as result got empty list, check loaded myDoc - it's full... please see screen in my edit

Comment: @Kirill: Doh, I missed out the `.Root` bit - fixing... try now. (I'm assuming that `Library` is the root element.)

Comment: Oh, thanks - now it's ok... yep need to spend a lot of time to know all  required information. Thanks for your help Also i'm i correctly understand usage of elements `Descendants() and Elements()` ?

Comment: @Kirill: Well I don't really know what your understanding of those methods is, so I can't easily say whether or not it's correct.

Comment: @Jon Skeet mean `Descendants()` as i understand return a collection of all elements inside it. like in my example if i call `Descendants("Library")` - i'll get all <Book>, and if i call `Elements("Book")` i'll get all elements inside <Book> - <Author>, <Genre> etc. Am i correct?

Comment: @Kirill: No. `Descendants(name)` will only give the descendants with that name - but it will give *all* of them rather than just child elements. `Elements(name)` will also only give elements with that name, but only direct child elements. I suggest you read the documentation in MSDN - and experiment for yourself - to understand the differences further.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your XML structure is same as what you shown in the question(`Library` has multiple `Book` elements and each `Book` has `Author`,`Name` etc...).

```
string xml="<Library> Your actual xml shown in question goes here</Library>";
var xElem = XElement.Parse(xml);
foreach (var book in xElem.Elements("Book"))
{
  string author = book.Element("Author").Value;
  string someNewVariableYouWantToAssignTo = author;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe XElement.Parse will *ever* return null.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. Used to the null checking !

Comment: You should only check for null when something can *actually* return null - otherwise most of your code will be polluted with pointless checks.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use one Linq query for load XML file.

 
For example:

```
string resource = @"<Library>
                      <Book>
                         <Author>Harrison FORD</Author>
                         <Name>Unknown Name</Name>
                         <Year>2000</Year>
                         <Genre>Unknown Genre</Genre>
                         <BookID>fc29b1cf-be41-4ed8-b101-5355396fef10</BookID>
                       </Book>
                       <Book>
                         <Author>Unknown Author</Author>
                         <Name>Unknown Name</Name>
                         <Year>2000</Year>
                         <Genre>Unknown Genre</Genre>
                         <BookID>29b6d74b-71b3-4df6-af0b-d676ff5d23ad</BookID>
                        </Book>
                      </Library>";

XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(resource);

var booksLib = (from book in document.Descendants("Book")
                select new Book()
                       {
                         Author = book.Element("Author").Value,
                         Name = book.Element("Name").Value,
                         Year = int.Parse(book.Element("Year").Value),
                         Genre = book.Element("Genre").Value,
                         BookID = book.Element("BookID").Value,
                        }).ToList();
```

You can use all Linq technics, like Where/Sort/Join/....